# Django: provide month and year number as parameter in a template for use in template tag

Tags: django, templates, datetime, tags

I am a Django Beginner.
I found this Django [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1485/) to show a simple calendar on my web page. The function needed 3 parameters that one can provide within the template as follows:

```
{% load calendar_tag %}
<div>
<div>Calendar: </div>
{% get_calendar for 10 2010 as calendar %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
        <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
    {% for week in calendar %}
    <tr>
        {% for day in week %}
        <td>{{ day.day }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```

How can I provide the number of the month and the year dynamically from the server, for example like:

```
{% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
```

It is not possible to have a block tag within a block tag.
I would appreciate to use this simple calendar.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would presume you would pass the params in when rendering the template in your view, like so:

```
def yourview(request, month, year):
    return render_to_string("template.html", {
        "month": month,
        "year": year,
    })
```

and then change `get_calendar` accordingly:

```
{% get_calendar for month year as calendar %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to present, how I fixed my problem, for others who might have similar problems:

With the help of the user fish2000, I managed my question like this:

My defined view:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

import datetime

def calender_view(request, template_name="custom_template_calender_tag.html"):
    d = datetime.date.today()
    recent_month = d.month
    recent_year = d.year
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and then changed `get_calendar` from

```
{% get_calendar  for 10 2010 as calendar %}
```

to

```
{% get_calendar  for recent_month recent_year as calendar %}
```

to provide and render the recent month and year dynamically in my template `custom_template_calender_tag.html`.