# How do I get the current year, month, and day for this template?

Tags: django

I need to pass current year, month, and day for the template tag. How do I do this?

```
   {% foo current_year current_month current_day %}
```

The 'foo' is my template tag. It accepts three arguments. which is the year, month and day.

Comment: Just pass them into the RequestContext in the corresponding view.

Comment: this is my base template. So I can't pass it from the view

Comment: If you want it to be in the base template and you want current date parts just take them from datetime inside the foo tamplatetag.

Comment: @Jingo I am doing some ajax stuff. So it is different for every page. For my base I need it to be current year, month, day. Those values change on other pages.

Comment: Create a tag named foonow

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't know?

Comment: What about you just add context processor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: provide month and year number as parameter in a template for use in template tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043509/django-provide-month-and-year-number-as-parameter-in-a-template-for-use-in-temp)